# Change the endpoint URL for Zoom App (Chatbot)

Tags: chatbot, zoom-sdk

I've created a Zoom App of Chatbot type. Initially, I defined the endpoint URL as my test URL (which were using ngrok) - now I want to change them. I went to Features but I do not find any option to change it.

Is there anyway to do it?

[image: Zoom]

Comment: So interestingly, there's a way to do that. You need to click on the right arrow (right beside the Chat Subscription) to expand the details. You can then change the URL. All solved!

Comment: Yep, I had the same problem, it took me a while to click the right arrow, by default it is folded.